# Add an upload-icon during uploading an image by CKEditor v4.2

Tags: javascript, upload, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor v4.2. When you are uploading an image, its looking like this (I removed some form fields):

[image: CKEditor v4.2 image upload]

The problem: you cant see, that you are uploading an image, because there are neither a progress bar nor an upload icon. Thats no well usability for inexperienced people.

How can I add an loading image like this using the API or manipulate the image-plugin:
[image]

I have no idea :( Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

No image but show text is OK.

```
type: "fileButton", 
id: "uploadButton",
filebrowser: "info:txtUrl",
label: d.lang.image.btnUpload,
onClick: function () {
 var input1 = this.getInputElement();
 input1.$.style = 'display:none';
 input1.$.before("file is uploading,please wait...");
 },
 'for': ['Upload', 'upload']
```